# Scroll PDF embedded in HTML

Tags: html, pdf

I have embedded a PDF file in Iframe. My html file has buttons "UP", "DOWN". When I click on these buttons, I want the pdf to scroll up or down.

Is there a way to control the pdf with javascript or any other way. I will be using Internet Explorer6 for this application and Acrobat pdf reader.

Comment: I am assuming you are aware that Internet Explorer 6 is a rotting corpse in the world of browsers and should not be used any more under any circumstances, and that you have your reasons for using it anyway (e.g. corporate Intranet).

Answer (score 3):

Hardly.

What you *might* be able to do is to put the `iframe` into a `div` with `overflow: auto`, and give the iframe a very large height value so the containing PDF is at full size. Make the surrounding `div` less tall than the iframe. When your buttons get clicked, scroll the surrounding div.

I haven't tested it so there may be some snag on the way, but this could work - and is probably the best you can do.

Answer (score 1):

You can read [PDF Open Parameters](http://partners.adobe.com/public/developer/en/acrobat/PDFOpenParameters.pdf).

Briefly you create an `<object>` tag such as `<object type="application/pdf" data="file1.pdf" width="500" height="650" ></object>` and you pass the parameters like `file1.pdf#toolbar=0 &scrollbar=0`. You can manage the up-down with links or images with html.

Comment: Soitris, 
With the pdf open parameters, when you pass the "file.pdf#page=3" , the pdf gets reloaded each time. I don't want pdf to be reloaded.

If I did not understand u, I apologize. Can you please explain your theory thru an example.