# Scroll PDF using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, pdf, iframe

I found a similar question [Scroll PDF embedded in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471709/scroll-pdf-embedded-in-html) but didn't see an answer. Does anyone have any suggestions for how to manipulate a PDF displayed within an iframe? Similar to the previous post link, I'm trying to scroll the PDF when the iframe doesn't have the focus (the host page does).

Thanks!

Comment: you could always set the focus to iframe first. How do you exactly want to scroll it? Animate or just change offset

Comment: Could you try my answer?

Comment: Just to change the offset. I'm trying what you said but still determining how to calculate the PDF size dynamically. Here's a sample of what I'm testing out. http://fiddle.jshell.net/mawaru/hx76LabL/. I think the best solution is to use PDF.js to do the rendering, but was hoping there's a different approach.

Comment: Use it:
 $.fn.resizeiframe=function(){
    $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
    });

}

then , use it as following : 
$('iframe').resizeiframe();

Answer (score 1):

Actually there is an answer in the link You provided:

> Hardly.
>
> What you might be able to do is to put the iframe into a div with
>   overflow: auto, and give the iframe a very large height value so the
>   containing PDF is at full size. Make the surrounding div less tall
>   than the iframe. When your buttons get clicked, scroll the surrounding
>   div.
>
> I haven't tested it so there may be some snag on the way, but this
>   could work - and is probably the best you can do.
>
> ~Pekka 웃

It's pretty easy. That's how you do it:

It depends on whether the iframe is "out-source", not from your server.
Let's just say that it is out-source

## CODE

```
<div id="iframeContainer" style="width: 800px; height: 600px; overflow: auto;">
   <iframe width="1800" height="6000" src="yourPDFfileSRC" scrolling="no">
   </iframe>
//You have to know exact width and height of PDF file
</div>
```

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("document").ready(function()
{
  $("#iframeContainer").scrollTop(1400);
});
</script>
```

## BONUS

You could animate it like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function()
    {
      $("#iframeContainer").animate({scrollTop: 1400}, 500); //500 - time of animation
    });
</script>
```