# How do I execute a content script in a chrome extension on a pdf viewed with chrome's viewer?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf, google-chrome-extension, embed

I want to be able to scroll using javascript on a pdf being viewed in chrome. However, the normal approach of using window.scrollBy() does not work, because the pdf itself is embedded in the page, so using window.scrollBy() on the parent page basically does nothing.

Is there any way I access run my content script in the embedded document so I can scroll?

Comment: Not sure if the link helps but it seems hard to achieve. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3471709/scroll-pdf-embedded-in-html

Comment: I appreciate the link - it does seem to be something that won't come easily. Chrome does use <embed> and not iframes for the external pdf, though, so I thought there might be a slightly easier solution.