# Hide/Disable element when scrolling, and as soon as scrolling stop, make it appear again

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to create a div tag to cover an embed tag, and did a little javascript so user can not right click the pdf inside embed tag to download it (I know it is useless, I doing this because my customer requested it). And this is the main part:
I want user still be able to scroll to pdf.
I programmed the scroll so that everytime user scroll, the div tag mentioned above will disappear, SO THAT USERS CAN SCROLL THROUGH THE PDF. But as soon as they stop scrolling, it will appear again, to prevent user from right click the pdf.
This is my code so far:

```
var wheeling;
window.addEventListener('wheel', function (e) {
        if (!wheeling) {
            console.log('start wheeling!');
            document.querySelector("#lesson_pdf").style.display = "none";
        }

        clearTimeout(wheeling);
        wheeling = setTimeout(function() {
            console.log('stop wheeling!');
            document.querySelector("#lesson_pdf").style.display = "block";
            wheeling = undefined;
        }, 300);
    });
```

My html:

```
<div>
    <div style="position: relative;">
        //the embed tag I want to cover
        <embed src=" {{ getImageFile($pdf_src) }}" class="tw-w-full tw-h-[500px] pdf-reader-frame" style="position: absolute;">
    </div>
    //The div tag I mentioned
    <div style="position: absolute;
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;
                display: block;
                z-index: 1;" id="lesson_pdf">
    </div>
</div>
```

The thing is, it doesn't work as expected. I sometimes have to scroll a lot of time before be able to scroll through the pdf file. Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

If your goal is to "to prevent user from right click the pdf", why not just disable the context menu? You can do that using the contextmenu event. It will be more efficient than displaying and hiding a div overlay (unless that was a super specific client request?)

```js
const img = document.querySelector("img")

img.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  return false
})
```

```html
<img src="http://via.placeholder.com/640x360" />
```

Comment: I'm working with a embed, not a img. I tried it, your javascript only works on img, it doesn't work on embed tag.

Comment: @jpesa apologies, I thought it would have the same effect with an embed.

Answer (score 0):

I hope below code will help you.don't forget to add the css

```js
var preventElement = document.getElementById('embed-document');
preventElement.addEventListener("contextmenu", (e) => {
e.preventDefault();
});
```

```css
embed {
            background:#cccccc;
            pointer-events: none;
        }
```

```html
<div>
    <div id="embed-document">
      <embed src="https://www.w3.org/WAI/ER/tests/xhtml/testfiles/resources/pdf/dummy.pdf" class="tw-w-full tw-h-[500px] pdf-reader-frame">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If the amount of different pdf that you would need to display is not many, this might be a good solution.

[Scroll PDF embedded in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3471728/17833755)

> What you might be able to do is to put the iframe into a div with
> overflow: auto, and give the iframe a very large height value so the
> containing PDF is at full size. Make the surrounding div less tall
> than the iframe. When your buttons get clicked, scroll the surrounding
> div.

The downside of this is that you would need to manually set the embed element height to be the same as the PDF full height with all the pages visible.

The run snippet in Stackoverflow using Chrome might not work because of some sandbox plugin error. But I tried and it works outside of a sandbox (using VS Code and live server) and the snippet run works using the Firefox developer version. I tested it on embed tag and it works as well.

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  
  /* The height that you want for your PDF viewer */
  height: 500px;
}

.embed-cover {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 1000;
  
  /* Must be same as embed height */
  height: 1000px;


  /* Just for demonstration, remove this part */
  background: red;
  opacity: 0.25;
}

embed {
  width: 100%;
  
  /* Must be same as embed-cover height */
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper" onContextMenu="return false;" >
  <div id="embed-cover" class="embed-cover">asd</div>
  <embed src="https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf" />
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Not intending to "Rain" on any of the prior answers, as they will stop "some of the innocents, like the disabled, some of the time" (NOT DDA/508 compatible is it?) However it will not stop those that are especially after the contents. So it is trivial to open a linked download file, data uri or blob (which it has to be). and antisocial to block usage.

What is inherent in PDF handling is tucked into the small print that allows it to be Openly Used as a Public Domain Standard.

> An interactive PDF
> processor interacts with a user while processing the PDF file and as a consequence may read or write
> PDF files.

**In other words there SHOULD be full Accessibility to be a compliant PDF edit/reading processor.**

[image]